# simulate form login through scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to simulate a login into a website to scrape some data. The following is the source for the form that I got from my browser:

*form method="POST" action="/account/login/" id="login_form" class="submit_form"
div style='display:none'>/div>input type="hidden" name="next" value="/"*

In scrapy, I do the following as is suggested in the documentation.

```
def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response, 
                                      formdata={'username': self.uname, 
                                                'password': self.key},  
                                                 callback= self.afterlogin)]


def afterlogin(self, response):
    #check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
         self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
    else:
        return Request(url="http://example.com",
                           callback=self.parse_Page)
```

However, I don't seem to be logged in, I don't get any error per se in the logs. I am not sure if I am missing something in the form data?It does appear from the logs that I am being redirected:

DEBUG: Redirecting (301)
followed by 
DEBUG: Crawled (404)

any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: A simple demo is here https://github.com/nabinkhadka/movies-details-scraper

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that adding the formxpath argument with the xpath for the login form solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that instead of the login request returning a response with a "set-cookie SESSION=1234567890ABCD" header (which is session cookie that presumably scrapy handles for you), that it returns some other sort of login token (e.g. could be in the response body) which you then need to do something else with (e.g. submit to a second/differnet page/handler).

THe best way to work out what's going on would be to use a tool such as FireBug (A firefox extension) to analyse the request/response data when you log in manually, to see if you can identify what and how they store the login state information.